Why am I facing this error while trying to do "catkin build" of a project I just cloned from Github? Eigen3 library issue
So I'm trying to run this project here: A ballbot on ROS, https://github.com/CesMak/bb
I've successfully run and even tried to install with sudo apt-get install libeigen3-dev. It doesn't work, and I have no idea what I have to do with the .cmake file as I'm new to C++, what should I edit so that I get to install all the packages?


There is a pull request in the GitHub link which you've shared. The Pull Request is the same problem which you're facing.
